# Smallest stabilizer codes with transversal CCZ or CS gates?

Tags: stabilizer-code, logical-gates

It [has been shown](https://arxiv.org/abs/2210.14066) that $[[15,1,3]]$ quantum Reed-Muller code is the smallest stabilizer code with a transversal T gate.
What are the smallest codes with transversal CCZ or CS gates (which are the other examples of level 3 operators in Clifford hierarchy)? Is it $[[8,3,2]]$ color code for CCZ? What about CS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same paper covers the cases of CCZ and CS (see lemma 4). It's the same code that is the smallest distance 3 code. If you want to extend to distance 2 error detecting codes, I don't know what the limits are.

Full disclosure: I'm one of the authors of the linked paper.

Comment: Thanks! I must have missed that. Great paper btw!